# Extension of a homomorphism from $(H \leq G) \xrightarrow{\varphi} X$ to $G \xrightarrow{\psi}X$ -- Is this a correct diagram?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, diagram-chasing

I want to make sure that I am understanding correctly the idea of a homomorphism $(H \leq G) \xrightarrow{\quad \varphi \quad} X$ being "extended" to a homomorphism $G \xrightarrow{\quad \psi \quad} X$. I'll first take an inclusion arrow $H \xrightarrow{\quad i \quad} G$. Then I'll take elements $h \in H \cap G$ and $g \in (G - H \cap G) $. Then $\psi$ is an "extension" of $\varphi$ which changes the domain $H$ to a group $G$ that contains $H$, such that $\psi(h) = \psi(i(h)) = \varphi(h)$. In addition though, we can also perform an operation $\psi(g)$ that cannot be done with $\varphi$. I've attempted to illustrate this with the diagram below. Let a black path commute with any blue or red path, but do not allow any path that has a **blue arrow** to commute with any path that has a **red arrow**. Then the extension I outlined above can be represented as such:

[image]

Does this correctly represent the principle of extension of a homomorphism?

Comment: Arrows in the left side of the diagram are not even group morphisms, and you do not need to think,.. or, rather, you should not be even thinking about elements at all. You only need the right triangle. You're given $i$ and $\phi$, and you want to construct $\psi$, which will be called extension of $\phi$ along $i$, if it exists.

Comment: The triangle in black lines is exactly what we want for "extension". The rest of your diagram would suggest that $\varphi(h)=\psi(g)=\psi(h)$ for all $h$ and $g$, which is in parts superfluous and false.

Comment: @FShrike Please read what I wrote in the diagram description: "Let a black path commute with any blue or red path, but do not allow a blue path to commute with a red path." To wit, instead of drawing a checkmark in parts of the diagram that commute with each other, I used coloring for each path. $\psi(g)$ is a red path and thus is not treated as equal to $\varphi(h) = \psi(h) = \psi(i(h))$, which is a blue path. I can add a bit more clarification if people missed this part.

Comment: A couple comments I guess to summarize my thoughts: (1) the diagram isn't necessarily "incorrect" per se, aside from the comment that if you have a diagram of groups typically you'd want your arrows to be homomorphisms, which your colored arrows are not. (2) anybody well familiarized with groups and the concept you're thinking about likely finds your diagram strange and unneccesary and agree with @xsnl that you only need the right-hand side of the diagram, but (3) that doesn't really matter as long as you find it a useful summary of the concept for the sake of your own comprehension.

Comment: @xsnl Is there some hard and fast rule within category theory that requires all arrows and objects be part of the same ambient diagram? I can omit saying I'm in $\mathrm{Grp}$ if that causes confusion by implying that all objects are groups. I wouldn't mind a **source** that says you aren't allowed to and you get diagrams that are "illegitimate" or "fall apart". If any $h \in H$ is also in $G$, is equal to itself under the inclusion into the group $G$, and its image under $\psi$ is equal to its image under $\varphi$, then I would prefer to keep that structure in the diagram.

Comment: @Nate Colour coding is not good to rely on in a diagram. As commented by a few of us now, the right hand diagram is entirely sufficient.

Comment: @Nate There are two hard and fast rules in mathematics in general. First one is to always use conventional form and, ehhh (hard to find the exact word)... Style of notation unless you have a compelling reason to use something original. Second one is to write down important things and do not write down extraneous and unimportant things. You slowly learn what is accepted and important by reading a lot of mathematical texts.

Comment: I think this is the idea you are going for. 

You can make this more succinct by declaring an extension $\psi$ to simply be a map such that for $i:H \hookrightarrow G$ we have that $\psi \circ i=\varphi$. This is basically just a single triangle (which I cannot make in mathjax)

that looks like $X \leftarrow_{\varphi} H \hookrightarrow_{i} G$ and the "hypotnuse" should be a map $\psi: G \to X$ making that diagram commute.

Comment: On the level of elements it is a homomorphism such that for all $h \in H$, $\psi(h)=\varphi(h)$ or if you wish to be more morphism-centric and not identify $H$ with its structure as a subset of $G$, for all $h \in H$ $\psi(i(h))=\varphi(h)$ for all $h \in H$.